# how to match RefMut<Enum>?

Tags: rust, refcell

I'm not very skilled with rust RefCell

and i want to know how to solve the following error.

I would be very grateful if someone could answer my question.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;


enum Node {
    Branch { name: String },
    Leaf { name: String },
}

fn test_match(node: &Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
    let borror_mut_node = RefCell::borrow_mut(node);
    match borror_mut_node {
        Node::Branch { name } => name.push_str("b"),
        Node::Leaf { name } => name.push_str("l"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let node = Node::Branch { name: "test-" };
    let node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(node));
    test_match(&node);
}
```

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b05660d58d16dc6ba4b0f285cee028f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to declare `borror_mut_node` mutable, match on`*borror_mut_node` and then take mutable reference to the inner field.

```rust
fn test_match(node: &Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
    let mut borror_mut_node = RefCell::borrow_mut(node);
    match *borror_mut_node {
        Node::Branch { ref mut name } => name.push_str("b"),
        Node::Leaf { ref mut name } => name.push_str("l"),
    }
}
```

You can simplify it further by removing `borror_mut_node`. You don't need it.

```rust
fn test_match(node: &Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
    //let  borror_mut_node = RefCell::borrow_mut(node);
    match *node.borrow_mut() {
        Node::Branch { ref mut name } => name.push_str("b"),
        Node::Leaf { ref mut name } => name.push_str("l"),
    }
}
```

Another way is by matching on the mutable reborrow.

```rust
fn test_match(node: &Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
    //let  borror_mut_node = RefCell::borrow_mut(node);
    match &mut *node.borrow_mut() {
        Node::Branch { name } => name.push_str("b"),
        Node::Leaf { name } => name.push_str("l"),
    }
}
```